# CSS not working properly when trying to align text with rowspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What i am trying to do is to make HTML similar to this [image](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3281770/9ac7e839540ca063a1966fe38c5a0799).
I tried Below HTML with `table` and with `div` as well. but text is not aligning proper. Not sure what is the best way to do it. As i am using `bootstrap`.

Here is my `HTML` that i tried.

```css
h1{
font-size:45px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><h1>1</h1></td>
    <td>Shopping Cart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>small content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with  elements to get the result you want.

```
<div class="item">
    <span class="count">1</span>
    <div class="txt">
        <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
        <p>Manage Your Item list</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.count {
    float: left;
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 30px;
}
.txt {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.txt h2,
.txt p {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1{
font-size:45px;
}
#bottom{
   vertical-align:bottom;
   }
   
#top{
   vertical-align:top;
   }
   
 td{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:1;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><h1>1</h1></td>
    <td id='bottom'>Shopping Cart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='top'>small content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what if i change both text's font size with different one. then i think it will be trouble again.

Comment: check the css on the td tag.  I think the line-height gives you better spacing

Answer (score 1):

```
try this

<style>
.sc-col-4{
width: 33.33%;
background: #ddd;
height: 150px;
}
.left-box{
background:#007bff;
padding: 1.5rem; color: white;
padding-right: 3rem;
padding-left: 3rem;
margin-right:1.3rem;
float:left;
font-size: 50px;
}

.right-box{
  float: left;
}

</style>

<div class="sc-col-4">
<div class="left-box">1</div>
<div class="right-box">
<div style="padding-top: 1rem; font-weight:600; font-size: 1.25rem; color: #007bff;">$1.999,50</div>
<div style="color: #868e96; font-weight: 700;  font-weight: bold">INCOME</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working but the output comes like that due to the size of each cell in table try this :-

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><h1>1</h1></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:bottom">Shopping Cart</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top">small content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: still you can see 1 is not aligned proper with shopping cart text

Answer (score 0):

A solution using styles as mentioned above would probably be cleanest. But if you're looking for something purely within the `table` element, you could add a nested `table` as follows.

Hope this helps!

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>Shopping Cart</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>small content</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```